# OpenVPN port forwarding to emulate a static IP

Tags: openvpn

Here's the setup:  I have 1 server running OpenVPN at a remote location and 1 local client.  The server has multiple WAN IPv4 addresses.  I would like to use OpenVPN to dedicate one of the server's WAN IP addresses to the client.  That is, everything that the server receives on the dedicated IP should be forwarded (and appropriately masqueraded) to the client; the client should generally send everything over the tunnel device; and the server should use the dedicated IP address for all data sent by the client.

Is this possible?  I have OpenVPN up and running, but I'm hopeless at routing rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do NAT and map the VPN IP directly to the WAN IP (on the server):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $WAN_NET/$WAN_NET_SIZE -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -d $WAN_IP -j DNAT --to-destination $VPN_REMOTE_IP
```

What routing must look like depends on what you want to do. Probably you need an entry like this (if it's noth there yet; on the remote client):

```
ip route add $WAN_NET/$WAN_NET_SIZE via $VPN_PEER_IP
```

This can be part of the OpenVPN configuration so that the routing is set up automatically if the interface becomes available.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I had to make a few changes, but the solution was pretty much what you suggested.  "-i tun0" throws an error, so I used "-s $WAN-IP/24" instead.  Also, $TUN0_IP must be the client's TUN0 IP address, not the server's.

Comment: @FredMilton Maybe the name of your OpenVPN interface is not tun0 or this interface is not available when the firewall code is executed.

Comment: No, the error was that "-i" cannot be used in POSTROUTING. Regardless, everything works fine with my changes. Thanks again!

Comment: comments integrated in answer